# Combine multiple rows eliminating duplicates and concat multiple column

Tags: mysql, distinct, concatenation, group-concat

I am using mysql and want to do the following:

1. Take distinct of each column and concatenate if multiple distinct exists for a record

```
     user_id  pagetitle     companyname   Category1                         Category2               Category3
     509      Digital Arts  Digital Arts  Advertising, Media & Promotions   Audio Visual Equipment  Audio Visual Equipment- Rentals
     509      Digital Arts  Digital Arts  Advertising, Media & Promotions   Audio Visual Equipment  Audio Visual Equipment- Rentals
     509      Digital Arts  Digital Arts  Advertising, Media & Promotions   Audio Visual Equipment  Audio Visual Equipment- Rentals
     509      Digital Arts  Digital Arts  Advertising, Media & Promotions   Audio Visual Equipment  Audio Visual Equipment- Rentals
     509      Digital Arts  Digital Arts  Advertising, Media & Promotions   Outdoor Media           Advertising- Signs, Neon, Glow Etc
     509      Digital Arts  Digital Arts  Advertising, Media & Promotions   Outdoor Media           Advertising- Signs, Neon, Glow Etc
     509      Digital Arts  Digital Arts  Advertising, Media & Promotions   Printing & Printers     Digital Printing 
     509      Digital Arts  Digital Arts  Advertising, Media & Promotions   Printing & Printers     Digital Printing 
     509      Digital Arts  Digital Arts  Advertising, Media & Promotions   Printing & Printers     Digital Printing 
     509      Digital Arts  Digital Arts  Advertising, Media & Promotions   Printing & Printers     Flexographic Printing 

     user_id  pagetitle     companyname  Category1                       Category2                                                                        Category3
     509      Digital Arts  Digital Arts    Advertising, Media & Promotions Audio Visual Equipment, Outdoor Media, Printing & Printers, Printing & Printers  Audio Visual Equipment- Rentals, Advertising- Signs, Neon, Glow Etc, Digital Printing , Flexographic Printing
```

---

2. And also merge content from multiple columns to 1 eliminating the empty columns.

   Address buildingname    landmark    Locality    sublocality City    State   Country pincode
   5   Vaniga Valaagam     Old Bus Stand       Salem   Tamilnadu   India   636001

As if i use `concat()` with separators the above also includes empty and include multiple separators.

```
5, Vaniga Valaagam, , Old Bus Stand, , Salem, Tamilnadu, India - 636001
```

Can someone suggest a way to achieve both.

Comment: Looks like homework. Did you do anything to solve it yourself?

Comment: @juergen d - I am not a database person nor am i a developer. but still i did try to do a distinct, concat, group by options. But as per my it is going complex for my level.

Comment: 1. See normalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1:

```
SELECT user_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pagetitle SEPARATOR ', ' ) as pagetitle,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT companyname SEPARATOR ', ' ) as companyname,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Category1 SEPARATOR ', ' ) as Category1,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Category2 SEPARATOR ', ' ) as Category2,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Category3 SEPARATOR ', ' ) as Category3
FROM some_table
GROUP BY user_id
```

Part 2:

concat-ing multiple fields ommiting empty ones

```
SELECT concat(
  IF(field1>'',concat(field1,', '),''),
  IF(field2>'',concat(field2,', '),''),
  IF(field3>'',concat(field3,', '),'')
  ) as something
FROM somewhere
```

Putting it together:

```
SELECT concat(
  IF(user_id>'',concat(user_id,', '),''),
  IF(pagetitle>'',concat(pagetitle,', '),''),
  IF(Category1>'',concat(Category1,', '),''),
  IF(Category2>'',concat(Category2,', '),''),
  IF(Category3>'',concat(Category3,', '),'')
  ) as something
FROM
(
SELECT user_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pagetitle SEPARATOR ', ' ) as pagetitle,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT companyname SEPARATOR ', ' ) as companyname,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Category1 SEPARATOR ', ' ) as Category1,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Category2 SEPARATOR ', ' ) as Category2,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Category3 SEPARATOR ', ' ) as Category3
FROM some_table
GROUP BY user_id
) nicehomework
```